# kCFSocketAcceptCallBack not being called for WIFI connection with static IP

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, ip

I will try to be as detailed as I can. I am trying to connect to an acquisition unit from my iPhone in my app. We are using IP4 and the acquisition unit doesn't support DHCP so its always scanning for device with a specific static IP and port no.

Before I tested the connection between the unit and my iPhone, I created an adhoc network using my desktop and try it out with my iPhone. This is part of my code.

```
CFSocketContext CTX = { 0, description, NULL, NULL, NULL };
/* Create the server socket as a TCP IPv4 socket and set a callback */
/* for calls to the socket's lower-level accept() function */
TCPServer = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
                           kCFSocketAcceptCallBack
                           , (CFSocketCallBack)WiFiCallBack, &CTX);
    /* Set the port and address we want to listen on */
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

CFDataRef addressData = CFDataCreate( NULL, (UInt8*)(&addr), sizeof( struct sockaddr_in )      );
CFSocketSetAddress(TCPServer, addressData);
```

It works and I can do data transfer between my desktop and iPhone if I feed in the IP that was assigned to iPhone to the PC app on my desktop. However if I set a static IP for iPhone and try to get the PC app to connect to any device with that IP it doesn't work.

Same goes with my acquisition unit. The call back function is not called at all.

I am in desperate need of help so any form of help is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but your post is not very clear.

Are you are trying to establish a server socket on the iPhone, and connect to it from elsewhere?

This is going to be problematic for many reasons.

First is that your ip is not going to be the same.  When connected to WIFI, you will have an ip that is routable at least on the current network.

But when connected to 3g (or lte, etc), you will likely not be able to route to the ip given at all.

Even if you did have a fully routable ip address on some interface that existed long enough, iOS is not designed for this.  Your application will not be able to run efficiently in the background and listen to a server socket.  You can simulate this with persistent sockets and voip background mode.  However that requires a separate server component.

You could also try polling from the iPhone, that may satisfy your requirements.